# Why is the return value of args.length 6 when I provide 3 command line arguments for my program

Tags: java, arguments, command-line-arguments

When I provide my Java Command line arguments with this : `Calculate 3 * 3` and when I print `args.length` before making my operations, it returns 6 in the case of a multiplication.

Here is a screenshot of the results for `java Calculate 3 * 3`

[image]

Here is my code in two files:

1. Calculator.java
2. Calculate.java

Here is how to run it if Java is installed:

- Open your terminal, run `javac Calculate.java`
- When it compiles, run `java Calculate 3 * 3`

Note: Whenever you try a multiplication for this program, args.length is 6. The program expects one numbers as operands and an operator ("+", "-", "*", "/" for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division respectively). That program works fine for all operations except multiplication.

Calculator.java

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;

public final class Calculator {
  // TODO: Fill this class in.
  private final Map<String, BinaryOperator<Integer>> operators = new HashMap<>();
  
  public void registerOperation(String symbol, BinaryOperator<Integer> operator){
  
    operators.put(symbol.strip(), operator);
  
  }
  
  public int calculate(int a, String operator, int b){
  
    return operators.get(operator).apply(a,b);
    
  }
 
}
```

Calculate.java

```
public final class Calculate {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args.length);
    System.out.println(args[2]);

    if (args.length != 3) {
      System.out.println("Usage: Calculate [int] [operator] [int]");
      return;
    }

    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    // TODO: Register the four "basic" binary operators: +, -, *, /
    calculator.registerOperation("+", (a, b) -> a + b );
    calculator.registerOperation("-", (a, b) -> a - b );
    calculator.registerOperation("*", (a, b) -> a * b );
    calculator.registerOperation("/", (a, b) -> a / b );

    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String operator = args[1];
    int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

    System.out.println(calculator.calculate(a, operator, b));
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the results of printing the args.

Comment: I just edited the question to add the results

Comment: Change `System.out.println(args);` to `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));`

Comment: When I run `java Calculate 5 * 5 ` it returns `[5, Calculate.class, Calculate.java, Calculator.class, Calculator.java, 5]` @ElliottFrisch

Comment: My guess is that the * symbol returns all the files in the directory, just as you said in your answer @ElliottFrisch

Comment: I managed to solve the issue with some tweaks

Comment: Post text rather than images when practical. And learn how to print an array. Hint: `Arrays` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` has a special meaning (all files in the current directory) to the command interpreter that starts `java`. This happens for all programs. Quote the `*`.

```
java Calculate 3 "*" 3
```

My advice would be to handle standard input (not arguments).

Comment: When I run `java Calculate 5 "*" 5` it returns `[5, Calculate.class, Calculate.java, Calculator.class, Calculator.java, 5]`

Comment: @EbillsonGRANDJEAN Try `java Calculate 5 '*' 5` then. I'm on a mac. You didn't say what operating system. But I would guess Windows now. This is the same thing that happens when you do `dir *`

Comment: It won't work, and I see why

Comment: It won't work, and I see why. Part of your answer helped me. Actually it doesn't matter how I put the `*`, what matters is that it's a `*`. Since it's a `*` it makes the command line have 6 arguments because `*` lists all the files in my directory (4 in total). Hence, the first and the last argument are the operands, in our example 5 and 5 or 3 and 3. The 4 other arguments are the `.java` two classes I created and the two classes Java generated when I compile my code. To solve that issue, I just took this factor into account